# Application streaming using VNC

Tags: vnc

From what I have researched, VNC seems like a great tool for remotely accessing desktops. Could someone, please tell me, if it is possible to stream stand alone Linux applications using VNC? Alternatively, if you know other methods to stream Linux applications.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just stream linux applications, look into ssh with X forwording (ssh -X). There are many clients that work for this such as putty w/xming for windows, x11 for mac, or any linux desktop with a gui. This method is encrypted as well and is integrated into the client window manager.

As far as VNC is concerened, it wont work because of its technology. VNC just takes screenshots and slings it over the network. VNC doesnt know of window locations and can't identify what windows are or where they are located.

Comment: Thats a good point. However, ssh X forwarding is really slow over low bandwidth networks. I tried it and it had large latency issues. Secondly, I want to use a web based client. For VNC I was able to use noVNC. I was unable to find a web based client for other X forwarding protocols. Any ideas?